# void* points to struct?

Tags: c, arrays, struct

I want to create a void* 1d array, each pointer in each cell points to struct that i wrote (it has to be void* array, not sturct array for some reasons<sup>†</sup>) , so far i wrote this:

```
typedef struct
{
 int weight;
 int amount;

} Banana;

void* makeBanana(){
Banana new;
new.weight = 1;
new.amount = 6;

void* p = &new; //its Legal??
return p;
```

Now, after that, i want to store this p in a dynamic array of void* pointers, each void* pointer points to anothe Banana, i wrote this:

```
void* ptrToBananaArray  = (void*)malloc(3); //3 is just example of lenght
ptr[0] = makeBanana();
```

Is this ok, or not? and if not, what is the correct way??

---

<sup>†</sup> Reason for using `void*` instead of `Banana*`:
its because i have a generic code elswhere that get only `void*` types, so here its banana, but in future it will want to get also a tomato or onion or something else, so it must be void*

Comment: NG. `void* p = &new;return p;` : `p` is point to local variable. invalid in outside scope.

Comment: makeBanana() is supposed to return a pointer to a void which makes no sense.

Comment: If you use `void*`, your code will be harder to write and read. You specified "not sturct array for some reasons" - what are these reasons? You should describe them so we can understand whether they are more important than having clean code.

Comment: @anatolyg its because i have a generic code elswhere that get only void* types, so here its banana, but in future it will want to get also a tomato or onion or something else, so it must be void*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sample code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct
{
 int weight;
 int amount;

} Banana;

void *makeBanana(){
    Banana *new;
    new = malloc(sizeof(Banana));
    if(new != NULL){
        new->weight = 1;
        new->amount = 6;
    }
    return new;
}

int main(void){
    void ** ptr  = (void**)malloc(3*sizeof(void*));
    ptr[0] = makeBanana();
    Banana *bananap = ptr[0];
    printf("weight: %d, amount: %d\n", bananap->weight, bananap->amount);
    free(ptr[0]);
    free(ptr);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: How is this code different from original one and why did you do these changes?

Comment: 1) return heap area(by malloc) 2) `void**` as array of `void*`

Comment: Reason 1) until the lifetime of the heap is released. 2) `void* ptrToBananaArray  = (void*)malloc(3);` Mistake a lot of sense. 1st `void` not equal `void*`

Comment: @BLUEPIXY and if i want to increase ptr by 1, i used realloc like this:
ptr  = (void**)realloc(1*sizeof(void*)); but it tells me :
"warning: passing argument 1 of ‘realloc’ makes pointer from integer without a cast"..whats wrong?

Comment: @user3729959 `realloc` needs two argument. E.g `new_pointer = realloc(old_pointer, new_size)`

Comment: @BLUEPIXY i see, so its not "increasing" the array, it makes new array + 1, copy the items, and create new pointer to point on this "new" array. correct?

Comment: @user3729959 yes, its copied old pointer point to contents in case returned a new pointer to extend the size. It is preferable to extend a certain collectively size than extended one by one in the case of often extend for that(Because there is a case in which the copy occurs each realloc).

Comment: The contents of that amount if the size is reduced is released.

Answer (score 2):

It is illegal to return a pointer to a variable which was create inside the function, as the memory which holds the variable is not statically allocated anymore and a different variable may overwrite it.

Answer (score 1):

You have a typo.

```
Banan new;
```

Should probably be `Banana new;`
Apart from this there is fundamental problem in your function makeBanana(). You shouldn't return address of local variable as it is invalid as soon as function returns.

You should allocate the struct with malloc:

```
Banana* new = malloc( sizeof( *new ) );
new->weight = 1;
```

and return the pointer:

```
return new ;
```

Finally, it would be great to change the name of variable, not to confuse the readers with `new`.

Comment: I didn't see much sense in posting another answer, feel free to improve.